# how to get id3tag for streaming mp3 url from api 8 above in android

Tags: java, android

how to  get metadata of mp3 or mp4 from api 8 but don't want to use ffmpegMediametadataretriever library because this library have 13 mb size and its not a good solution for me! can anyone help me for  getting id3tag of an URL ?!! i tried so many ways such as available java libraries for id3tag i could not make it. help me please.any code sample I appreciate. 
the code i used:

Mp3File mp3file = null;
            try {
                mp3file = new Mp3File("http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2009.mp3");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedTagException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvalidDataException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

```
        if (mp3file.hasId3v1Tag()) {
            ID3v1 id3v1Tag = mp3file.getId3v1Tag();
            System.out.println("Track: " + id3v1Tag.getTrack());
            System.out.println("Artist: " + id3v1Tag.getArtist());
            System.out.println("Title: " + id3v1Tag.getTitle());
            System.out.println("Album: " + id3v1Tag.getAlbum());
            System.out.println("Year: " + id3v1Tag.getYear());
            System.out.println("Genre: " + id3v1Tag.getGenre() + " (" + id3v1Tag.getGenreDescription() + ")");
            System.out.println("Comment: " + id3v1Tag.getComment());
        }
```

Comment: I try to write it on sd card and read it by this mp3agic library but what if the file has a big size ?!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it Finally, just add arm-fmmr.aar to app libs folder and then add this lines in build.gradle:

```
   repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
   }

   dependencies {
   compile (name:'arm-fmmr', ext:'aar')
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever):

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource("some MP3 URL");
mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
byte [] artwork = mmr.getEmbeddedPicture();

mmr.release();
```

Comment: i used FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever but gradle dependency making my apk size up to 16 mb !!!

Comment: Yes, as the documentation states, you can also use the prebuilt AAR's to generate multiple APK's.